# Wrong answer of average function?

Tags: c, function, variables, integer-division

I'm practically new to C programming and I've been trying to get a simple average function right, but the fractional part of the answer keeps messing up...??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

float cal(int num1,int num2,int num3);

int main(){
    int a,b,c;
    float avg;

    a=10;
    b=5;
    c=11;

    avg=cal(a,b,c);
    printf("Average is : %E\n", avg);
    return 0;
}

float cal(int num1,int num2,int num3){
    float avg1;
    avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3;
    return avg1;
}
```

The answer (`avg`) should be `8.66666666667`, but instead I get `8.00000000`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer division here. Cast it to `float` (at least one of them) or use float literals before division to force it to use float division.

For example, change

```
avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3;
```

to

```
avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/(float)3;  // 1. cast one to float
avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3.0f;      // 2. use float literals
```

Comment: @user3889963 As programmers, we are all blind from time to time. :P

Comment: Instead of a cast, use a float literal: `avg1 = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3.0f;`

Answer (score 3):

It is because all operands are integer in here `(num1+num2+num3)/3`. So you get an integer division, that is later cast to a float (i.e. upon the assignment, but after the evaluation).

You need to make one of the division operands a `float`, so the rest will be converted. And the division will be a `float` division.

E.g:

```
(num1+num2+num3)/(float)3
(num1+num2+num3)/3.0f
((float)(num1+num2+num3))/3
```

Note that the additions are still integer additions, because of parentheses.
A nice read on the conversion rules is [`here`](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html).

Answer (score 3):

Change this

`avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3;`

to this

`avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/(float)3`;

That way you force a division by a float.

With your code you actually perform integer division, which means that the decimal digits get discarded. Then the result of the division is assigned to a float number, but the decimal digits are already gone. That's why you need to cast at least one operand of the division to a float, in order to get what you want.

Comment: @chux Yes, `3.0` is a `double`. @G.Samaras If you want a `float` you can use `3.0f`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3;
```

to

```
avg1=(float)(num1+num2+num3)/3;
```

If you perform integer division then result will also be integer. 
As `avg1` is already declared as float, you can cast the result of the operation to get float value.

Answer (score 2):

Force the division to be perfomed in floating point

```
avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3.0f;
```

What happens in your case is, you perform the an integer division and *then* convert it to float:

Resulting type of `(num1+num2+num3)/3` is an integer, while the type of `(num1+num2+num3)/3.0f` is a float.

Integer division will give the result without the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code further

```
float cal(int num1,int num2,int num3){
return ((num1+num2+num3)/3.0);
}
```

Just change the value 3 to 3.0 that's enough. because the up-casting has to be made manually the compiler only perform the down-casting.

Comment: Interesting suggestion with a subtle effect:  This does a `(float) ((double) sum/(double))`.  Had code been `return ((num1+num2+num3)/3.0f);` --> `(float) sum/(float)`.  The first is typically more accurate while the later typically more efficient.  IAC, it does depend on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and makes insignificant difference with OP's sample integers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the well pointed out need to use floating point division rather than integer division, typical `float` will not provide a precise number like `8.66666666667` but only to 6 or so digits.  Further, conversion of typical `int` (32-bit) may result in truncation when converting to `float`.

For a more precise answer with 11 digits to the rights of `.`, use `double` instead of `float`

```
double cal(int num1,int num2,int num3){
    double avg1;
    avg1=(num1+num2+num3)/3.0;  // 3 --> 3.0
    return avg1;
}

int main(void){  // added void
    int a,b,c;
    double avg;

    a=10;
    b=5;
    c=11;

    avg=cal(a,b,c);
    // printf("Average is : %E\n", avg);
    printf("Average is : %.11E\n", avg); // Print to 11 digits after the dp.
    return 0;
}
```